# How can I attach a screenshot to a testcase for a failed test with XUnit

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xunit, functional-testing

We are going with XUnit to run Selenium Functional Tests. In Microsoft Azure Devops, we have a pipeline stage which runs our functional tests.

If the test fails, I want to take a screenshot using the Web Driver and attach it to the test results output.

I know it can be done with NUnit (using TestContext), but how can I achieve this using XUnit? Not sure if this is correct, but is there a way using REST APIs that I could somehow achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like xUnit will support it in version 3.0. Currently the teams I work on use the API listed by Cece to push screenshots per-test.

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/621

Answer (score 0):

XUnit still doesn't support TestContext, check here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2133

After taking the screenshots, you may consider using [Attachments - Create Test Result Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API to attach the screenshot to a test result:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: This api could attach a file to a test result. You could add a powershell task in your pipeline to invoke the api.

Comment: You can see the api need to pass "testCaseResultId" when you create attachment.